# visual basic 6 Image Class

Tags: image, vb6

The following code is the Form code which changes an image or informs the user if the image has already changed. In the form, I have an Image control named **Image1** whose Picture property has to be changed. I'm just asking for help on how to make a class module(.cls) from this code.

```
Private Image1Color As String

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Image1Color = "Green"

End Sub

Private Sub CheckIn1_Click()

    If Image1Color = "Green" Then
        Image1.Picture = LoadPicture ("Color\red1.jpg")
        Image1Color = "Red"
    Else
        MsgBox ("This table is already occupied")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to literally reuse your form code you can do the following:

ImageControlWrapper.cls:

```
Private m_ksColor_Green As String = "Green"
Private m_ksColor_Red As String = "Red"

Private m_sImageColor As String
Private WithEvents m_oImageControl As Image

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    m_sImageColor = m_ksColor_Green

End Sub

Public Sub Attach(ByRef in_oImageControl As VB.Image)

    Set m_oImageControl = in_oImageControl

End Sub

Private Sub m_oImageControl_Click()

    If m_sImageColor = m_ksColor_Green Then
        Set m_oImageControl.Picture = LoadPicture("Color\red1.jpg")
        m_sImageColor = m_ksColor_Red
    Else
        MsgBox "This table is already occupied"
    End If

End Sub
```

Test.frm:

```
Private m_oImageControlWrapper As ImageControlWrapper

Private Sub Form_Load

    Set m_oImageControlWrapper = New ImageControlWrapper
    m_oImageControlWrapper.Attach Image1

End Sub
```

I used string constants for the color purely so that the compiler can pick up a mistake if you mispell the constant. If you mispell the actual string, that's an annoying bug to fix. However, if you don't really need to use the string, you would be better off turning m_sImageColor into a Boolean or an enumerated type.